# "unable to find a medium container a live file system" when installing Ubuntu Server 20.04 from USB

Tags: boot, live-usb

When boot from UEFI and select "install Ubuntu", then the screen display

```
xhci_hcd 0000:24:00.0: init 0000:24:00.0 fail,-16
xhci_hcd 0000:2b:00.1: init 0000:2b:00.1 fail,-16
xhci_hcd 0000:2b:00.3: init 0000:2b:00.3 fail,-16
nouveau 0000:41:00.o: unknown chipset (fb72000a1)
```

[image: error message1]

After 1 minute later the screen shows

```
mount: mounting /dev/nvme2n1 on /cd rom failed: invalid argument
stdin: Invalid argument
stdin: Invalid argument
unable to find a medium container a live life system
Attempt interactive net form a URL?
```

[image: error message2]

I tried multiple times, but all failed. I have tried:

- usb3 stick plug in usb2 and usb3 port
- usb2 stick plug in usb2 and usb3 port

Specs:

- AMD 3975wx
- ASUS PRO WS WRX80E-SAGE SE
- Samsung DDR4-2933 ECC REG 64GB * 8
- several NVMe drivers
- ASUS EKWB GeForce RTX 3080

---

I need to add some detail about Ubuntu ISO, I checked the md5 and created a vm successfully.
I bought 2 new usb sticks, one is USB 2.0 and the other one is USB 3.0.
I gonna try to make a  Live USB to get more detail about the question.

Comment: The offer to download an ISO occurs (ie. your `*unable to find a medium container a live file system, Attempt interactive net download from URL?*` because no valid ISO is found on the media you are using... ie. either you failed to validate it prior to write to your installation media; or the write of the ISO to media is faulty... I have two answers in that question, you're problem is detected early on (*meaning your media is very faulty; or bad VM setup if virtual*) thus boot isn't attempted...

Comment: Maybe also helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot  (*I've written an answer on the actual message you are getting; without your typos though, but sorry I can't find it*)..  In QA we test for that message by corrupting our thumb-drives prior to boot; your thumb-drive contains *corrupted* media on it rather than a valid ISO.  The CDROM messages refer to invalid installation media as well...  In my experience the WRITE of ISO to media is most at fault; are you writing in a manner suitable for 20.04? using approved program?

Comment: Also check your box doesn't have bug in the firmware that have been fixed by upgrades you've not yet applied to your hardware...   That was another reason noted where this can occur (*most enterprise hardware had this fixed by firmware upgrades; some lower end consumer devices didn't get fixes though*)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: enter BIOS setup.

Select the "ADVANCED" menu and within this menu the option "PCI SUBSYSTEM SETTINGS"

Enable the option "SR-IOV SUPPORT"

press F10 to save and exit.

Ubuntu should install now (mine did ^^)

btw, If your desktop (once Ubuntu setup has finished) turns to be too colourful (you will understand what I mean if you experience it) a way to solve it is to switch off the integrated vga on the motherboard: shutdown the computer, find the vga switch close to the cmos battery and move it to off.

source:
https://support.punchtechnology.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/6636489490845-Fix-for-disappearing-SATA-ports-when-using-Ubuntu-Linux-with-ASUS-Pro-WS-WRX80E-SAGE-SE-WIFI-motherboards

Comment: i gonna try this later. the idc is far away from my home. thx!